# The last element of a recyclerView is being cutoff inside swipeToRefresh layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a recyclerView  is positioned inside a SwipeRefreshLayout  , the problem is the last element of the recyclerView is always cutoff. here is the Layout code of the fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.deliveries.DeliveriesFragment">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/DeliveryProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/deliveriesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: give bottom_margin=?actionbarsize i will work

Comment: Hi , Do you mean add it to the recycler view ?? can you explain more plz

Comment: yes add bottom margin in recyclerview

Comment: I did it like that it didnt work : android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: change parent layout to CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Didn't work too